# Include node_modules css in Vuejs application that uses scss

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, ej2-syncfusion

I have deployed my application to aws and I see that the application renders fine, except that the syncfusion controls do not render correctly. Google chrome console does not show any errors.
The application renders correctly in my local machine.

[image]

To fix this, it was suggested I move the `import '@syncfusion/**/styles/material.css'` statements in the individual vue component to App.vue (as documented [here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/textbox/getting-started/?no-cache=1#registering-vue-component)). I however get a "`Failed to resolve loader: sass-loader, You may need to install it`" error(the application has node-sass, sass-loader installed already).

How should I include css files along with scss files, in my application?

**Before: vocabulary.vue:**

```
<script>
import '@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css';
import '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-inputs/styles/material.css';
```

**package.json:**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
}
```

**vue.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/',
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vue-echarts',
    'resize-detector'
  ],
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**App.Vue:**

```
<style>
@import "../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css";
@import "../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-inputs/styles/material.css";
</style>
```

Comment: Did you make sure to run `npm install` after adding the loader to `package.json`?

Comment: Thanks @Phil. The application already had node-sass, sass-loader installed but as a last resort, I deleted the npm packages and reinstalled them again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the npm packages and re-installing them again fixed the issue.